# How can I wrap an F# Type in order to access its properties

Tags: f#, quotations

I don't know if this is actually a pattern so not sure where to start looking. I will try to explain what I want.

Given type `Foo` with members Bar and Baz, can I create a wrapper type `A<Foo>` that returns a mocked instance Foo such that I can write `A<Foo>.Bar ...`? The goal is that it can be used inside quotations e.g. `<@ A<Foo>.Bar > 1 @>`

To be clear. How do I implement `A`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a pattern.

If your is analyzing properties of `Foo` in some way, use a code quotation of type `Expr<Foo -> 'a>`, which would look like this:

```
let q = <@ fun (foo: Foo) -> foo.Bar @>
```

You can omit the type annotation `: Foo` if the type of the quotation is known from context:

```
let q : Expr<Foo -> 'a> = <@ fun foo -> foo.Bar @>
```

Many libraries use quotations this way, including the `query` computation expression and one of my favorites, Argu, a library for parsing command-line arguments.

Comment: And how do I implement A?

Comment: You don't implement `A`. A type cannot alter its set of members depending on its generic arguments. I assumed you already understood that and were asking for an alternative way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to do exactly what you want with a Type Provider, but this would likely be far more effort than it's worth.  In your situation, I would just use a mocking framework like [Foq](https://github.com/fsprojects/Foq/blob/master/Foq/Foq.fs), or if the use-cases are simple enough, just use object expressions:

```
type Foo =
    abstract member Bar: int

let mockFoo = 
    {new Foo with
        member __.Bar = 1
    }
```

Here's an example of something close to what you're looking for using Foq:

```
open Foq

type A<'a when 'a: not struct> = Mock<'a>

type Foo =
    abstract member Bar: int

<@ A<Foo>().Create().Bar > 1 @>
```

In this case, `Bar` will always be 0.  If you want it to be non-zero, you'll need to set it up, as follows:

```
<@ A<Foo>().Setup(fun f -> <@ f.Bar @>).Returns(2).Create().Bar > 1 @>
```